# How do I convert a JSON Object into a HTML table?

Tags: html, json, html-table

I've got a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 3, "ds": 4}
```

I'd like to convert it into a HTML table that looks like this:

```
name | Value
a     1
b     3
ds    4
```

Could anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's very simple with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('{"a":1,"b":3,"ds":4}');
  var html = '<table border="1">';
  $.each(jsonObj, function(key, value) {
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
  });
  html += '</table>';
  $('div').html(html);
});
```

Here is link to the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/T7eQg/1/).

**UPDATE:** an alternative way to achieve this is by using [a library called dynatable](https://www.dynatable.com/) to convert the JSON into a sortable table.

Comment: Your code is a lot simpler than the code I had and much cleaner. Thanks... saved my soul!

Answer (score 5):

You can use javascript:

```
<script type="text-javascript">
  var data = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 3,
    "ds": 4
  };
  // Create a new table
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  // Add the table header
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var leftRow = document.createElement('td');
  leftRow.innerHTML = "Name";
  tr.appendChild(leftRow);
  var rightRow = document.createElement('td');
  rightRow.innerHTML = "Value";
  tr.appendChild(rightRow);
  table.appendChild(tr);
  // Add the table rows
  for (var name in data) {
    var value = data[name];
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var leftRow = document.createElement('td');
    leftRow.innerHTML = name;
    tr.appendChild(leftRow);
    var rightRow = document.createElement('td');
    rightRow.innerHTML = value;
    tr.appendChild(rightRow);
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  // Add the created table to the HTML page
  document.body.appendChild(table);
</script>
```

The resulting HTML structure is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ds</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the link to the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Dv8T/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), with that, you can take your JSON data and bind it to HTML elements.

Updating is then done automatically, so you don't have to mess with that by yourself.

Here is a [list of examples](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/simpleList.html).