# Unable to process feed with JS

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have link to the feed quoted below and I want to display the data for it's elements in HTML file using JavaScript only. I'm tryin to make this in the console first but gettin error **Invalid JSON format**

Any ideas how can this be fixed and how to make it work? Thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var link = 'https://neon.epson-europe.com/frame/interfaces/newsroomcustom.php?json={"area":["blogarticle"],"tags":["Kids%20corner"],"limit":3,"offset":0,"language":"en","country":"GB","action":"getList","jsonp":"jsonp"}';
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: 'id=10',
    url: link + ";callback=?",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TestTest</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>article title should be here</h1>
  <p> subtitle should be here </p>
  <image src=" link to the image should be here ">
    <p>date should be here</p>


</body>
```

Comment: That link is returning JSONP, which won't validate as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to be more readable your JS, anyways what makes it all work is this property I added: `jsonpCallback: 'jsonp'`. Here is the full code modified:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var link = 'https://neon.epson-europe.com/frame/interfaces/newsroomcustom.php';
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
     jsonpCallback: 'jsonp',
    data: 'json={"area":["blogarticle"],"tags":["Kids%20corner"],"limit":3,"offset":0,"language":"en","country":"GB","action":"getList","jsonp":"jsonp"}&id=10',
    url: link + ";callback=?",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
});
```

Test and tell me if works for you.

Comment: Yeah, works great. Thank you. Because I'm newbie in JS, can you give me an advice how to get title, image and link for all blogarticles in the feed directly inside my body tag.



<h1>name</h1>
<img src="pic300">
<p class="date">launched</p>
<a href="urlslugs">See more</a>

Comment: I recommend you see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467785/how-to-convert-json-object-to-html-data) and also encourage you to use some JS libraries like [Vue](https://vuejs.org/)  or [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/), they will save you a lot of time and are good technologies to know.