# Create a Table in html using json data

Tags: php, html, json

How do i create a Table (`HTML`) with `JSON` data?
This is my `JSON` data:

```
{
"7627":
  {"amt":2000,"pc":"3","bId":"1"},
"7868":
  {"amt":0,"pc":"2","bId":"1"},
"7990":
  {"amt":0,"pc":"2","bId":"1"},
}
```

Comment: what you tried show the code

Comment: i just don't know how to parse this information and make table from it. This information is present in a variable

Comment: If you may use jquery or JS : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467785/how-to-convert-json-object-to-html-data

Comment: 1) Decode this Json, 2) Iterate loop 3) Display your data in tbale

Comment: https://eval.in/976599  . now you have array. iterate over it and create your html

Answer (score 0):

First decode into an Array:

```
$yourArray = json_decode($yourJsonString, true)
```

then build the Table with

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value) {
   echo "<tr><td> ...
```

**EDITED After update the question is duplicate**

Here is Your json value i changed into array

```
$array = json_decode{'
"7627":
  {"amt":2000,"pc":"3","bId":"1"},
"7868":
  {"amt":0,"pc":"2","bId":"1"},
"7990":
  {"amt":0,"pc":"2","bId":"1"},
"8214":  
  {"amt":0,"pc":"3","bId":"1"},
"10331":
  {"amt":0,"pc":"2","bId":"1"}
}', true);
```

after that this is the table view use by foreach:

```
echo '<table border="1px">';
foreach ($array as $key => $single){
    echo '<tr>
            <td>
                '.$key.'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$single['amt'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$single['pc'].'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$single['bId'].'
            </td>
        <tr>';  
}
echo '</table>';
```

I just echoed the values if you want to change you can use with concatenate operator for the table data(td)...