# Javascript: Put a JSON objects infromation to a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, object

I'm trying to solve this example that we were given.

```
<ul class="wrapper">
      <li class="form-row">
        <label id="label">ID</label>
        <label id="label">TYPE</label>
        <label id="label">STATUS</label>
        <label id="label">SPEED</label>
      </li>
      <li class="form-row-robot" id="robot1">
        <label for="topic">839</label>
        <label id="type">R-1000</label>
        <label id="status">ON</label>
        <label id="speed">0</label>
      </li>
      <li class="form-row-robot" *id="robot2"*>
        <label for="topic">240</label>
        <label id="type">R-2000</label>
        <label id="status">ON</label>
        <label id="speed">0</label>
      </li>
```

I have manually put in each *ID*, *TYPE*, *STATUS* and *SPEED*, in this html file. I have a list of JSON objects with the same information in my JavaScript file. That looks like this

```
var robot = {
Id : int,
Type : char,
Status : boolean,
Speed : int
}
```

Is there a easy way to do this? I want to still have the class *form-row-robot* and *id="robot2"* from the html file but each id will be robot + I. Seems like a long request but everything that can guide me into the right direction will help.

[How do I convert a JSON Object into a HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467785/how-do-i-convert-a-json-object-into-a-html-table) is an good solution to my problem but I have problem to put in the class="form-row-robot" id="robot1"?

I'm sorry if anything is blurry, I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: [Duplicate IDs are not allowed in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240240/why-are-duplicate-id-values-not-allowed-in-html). Also, you only showed a single JSON object, not a list. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77595021/edit) to show an example of the data you are starting with.

Comment: There is no JSON here.

Comment: Please read this Q/A: [What is JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: @kmoser, saw you edited your post three times. The "single JSON object" you are referring too, is an example on how the JSON objects look in my JavaScript.  Is the information important to you what the id actually is? If you are interested in  the starting data, read the HTML file.

Comment: @James, isn't a JSON Object JSON? The link I posted also calls it JSON Object?

Comment: A Javascript Object is not JSON, correct.  JSON would be a textual representation of that object, used to transfer data between systems typically.  example:  `let x = {name: 'test'}`, x is an Object.  `let y = '{"name": "test"}'`, y is a JSON string.

Comment: @James okay now I understand, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you’re trying to dynamically generate a list item (li) for each robot object in your JSON dataset, and embed it into an HTML structure. First, note that the id attribute in HTML should be unique across the entire document, so having multiple elements with the same id (like label, type, status, and speed) is not valid. You will need to modify those to either use class instead of id, or append unique identifiers to each id.

Here’s an example approach using vanilla JavaScript:

Assuming your robots data looks somewhat like this:

```
var robots = [
  { Id: 839, Type: 'R-1000', Status: 'ON', Speed: 0 },
  { Id: 240, Type: 'R-2000', Status: 'ON', Speed: 0 },
  // ... more robots
];
```

You would iterate over each object and generate the HTML needed:

// Get the wrapper element where you want to insert the robots details

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

// Loop through each robot and append the html structure
robots.forEach(function(robot, index) {
  var robotLi = document.createElement('li');
  robotLi.className = 'form-row-robot';
  robotLi.id = 'robot' + (index + 1); 
// Create a unique id for each robot

  // Create a string with the dynamic HTML for the current object
  var robotHtml = `
    <label for="topic">${robot.Id}</label>
    <label class="type">${robot.Type}</label>
    <label class="status">${robot.Status}</label>
    <label class="speed">${robot.Speed}</label>
  `;

  // Set the inner HTML of the list item
  robotLi.innerHTML = robotHtml;

  // Append the list item to the wrapper
  wrapper.appendChild(robotLi);
})
```

You’ll note that instead of using id for the labels (which should be unique), I’ve used class. For each of the robots, this will generate a new list item with the class form-row-robot and a unique id that is "robot" followed by the index of the iteration (plus 1 to start from robot1 instead of robot0).

Finally, remember to replace the example robots array with the actual JSON data you have. If the JSON data is in string format, you will need to parse it with JSON.parse(yourJsonString) before using it in the forEach loop.

Comment: There's no JSON in this answer or in the question.

Comment: Also the "for" attribute on a `<label>` element should have as its value the id of the related element.

Comment: Copy and paste from ChatGPT is forbidden to serve as answer in Stack Overflow.